# No way to show seconds in Gnome Classic clock

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic, clock

I cannot force clock in **Gnome Classic** to show seconds.
Tried within **dconf-editor**, changing all available clock settings:

**com > canonical > indicatior > datetime**
There I was trying by changing *custom-time-format* and setting *time-format* to *custom* and by checking *show-seconds*. Both does not work.

**org > gnome > desktop > interface**
I turned *clock-show-seconds* on. Nothing happened.

**org > gnome > gnome-panel > shell > clock**
*show-seconds* enabled, no reaction.

Also, I've been restarting system after each change.

Please, help - I need it for few things.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: com.canonical.indicator.appmenu.datetime.show-seconds works for me.  What version of ubuntu are you using?  Are you using the indicator-complete applet or the gnome-applets?  If you are unsure - please add a link to your question with a screenshot of your desktop.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I have set seconds on in all possible places same time and still no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an unusual issue - for myself, this works using `dconf-editor`

#### [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools]

[image]

Possibly you need to reinstall the package `indicator-applet-complete`

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

logout and login and then use `dconf-editor` as described above.

Comment: It works for me. I did this in dconf-editor, but i didn't reinstall indicator-applet-complete, but after that, everything works fine.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Lubuntu, and all I did was right-click on clock and opened it's settings. No matter how simple the dialog box is, you should always be able to see "Clock Format" and "Tooltip Format" fields.

In first one, all you have to do is type `%H:%M:%S`, and that's it. `H` stands for "Hours", `M` for "Minutes", and `S` for "Seconds".

Now, if you are not used, like myself for example, to American date format, which is month/day/year and can be really confusing, you can also change that in the second field. Type `%A %d.%m.%y.`. `A` stands for name of today's day, `d` for "day", `m` for "month", and so on.

Instead of dots, you can put anything else, like `/`, or `-`, depends on what you prefer.